# Restoring a Deleted Answer

Tags: support, answers

A new user responded to my [question on installing Ubuntu on an Asus X205](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551222/ubuntu-on-an-asus-x205-subnotebook/555867#555867) with an answer about installing on a very similar, closely related, machine. This info is very useful and I did give him/her kudos but now the answer has been deleted. I would encourage the mods to restore that answer which I can no longer see.

Please restore that answer. It is useful! I am the OP of the question. There is very little information about installing Ubuntu (or for that matter any Linux distro) on this breed of Bay Trail Intel Atom chips with a 32 bit UEFI (but a 64 bit capable CPU) and any useful information is very very welcome!

Answer (score 6):

OK,

- The answer wasnt really an answer.  It was more of a comment sharing some further insight.
- Since the poster only had 1 rep, they didn't have the right to post comments.

Thus, I've converted it to a comment which in-turn deletes the answer.